# Method to find available devices from 255 ip address

Tags: ruby, ssh, ping

I have 6 devices configured on IP address 1 to 255 in the range 192.168.1.X (where X = 1 to 255). I have written this program to ping and see available IP address to perform operations. But its taking so long to execute... 
can any one suggest a quick method to perform this?

Fork usage is also appreciated...

Here is the program:

```
server = "192.168.1"
for i in (1...255)
  system("ping -q -c #{timeout} #{server}.#{i} 2&>/dev/null")
  if $?.exitstatus == 0
    # operations
  end
end
```

Comment: `-c` is not `timeout` but `count`. To apply timeout use `-W` and/or `-w`. You may also speed this up by running each ping in a separate thread in which case you'll have all responses after a single timeout instead of 255*timeout.

Comment: or use `nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24` ping scan :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested with ruby 1.9.3 timing not bad;

```
[slmn@uriel ~]$ time ruby ipmap.rb 
"192.168.0.1"
"192.168.0.10"

real    0m2.393s
user    0m0.750s
sys     0m1.547s
```

I commented the areas if you want to do your operations threaded;

```
require 'ipaddr'

ips = IPAddr.new("192.168.1.0/24").to_range

threads = ips.map do |ip|
  Thread.new do
    status = system("ping -q -W 1 -c 1 #{ip}",
                    [:err, :out] => "/dev/null")

    # you can do your operations in thread like this
    # if status
    #   # operations
    # end

    # optional
    Thread.current[:result] = ip.to_s if status
  end
end

threads.each {|t| t.join}

# if you don't do your operations in thread
threads.each do |t|
  next unless t[:result]

  # operations

  #optional
  puts t[:result]
end
```

Comment: [child processes](https://gist.github.com/1944010) implementation on same machine is faster.